# The correct way to store complex form data in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, use-state

I have a complex form in React containing a dozen sub-components. It also includes my own form components that operate by not single values. Some parts of the form use trees of objects as data.

I have the main component (let's call it EditForm) which stores the whole object tree of data. I assume each component of this form should use a specific part of this main object. I should have the ability to store whole form data into JSON and read it back from JSON (and update all sub-components automatically when JSON changed).

The idea was to refresh only those parts of the form that required when I change the main JSON. But the code which handles this behavior is dramatically big and complex. I have to implement comparison functionality into each sub-component and also transfer parts of the main JSON into props of each sub-component.

```js
const [testobj, setTestobj] = useState({'obj1': {......}, 'obj2': {.......}, .......});

function revalidateSub(sub_name, value)
 {
  let t2 = cloneDeep(testobj);
  t2[sub_name] = value;
  setTestobj(t2);
 }

 return (<MySubComponent subobj={testobj['sub1']} ident={"sub1"} onUpdateData={v => revalidateSub('sub1', v)}/>)
```

(`subobj` is the piece of data which is controlled by a specific sub-component, `onUpdateData` is a handler which is called inside the subcomponent each time when it makes any changes to a controlled piece of data)

This scheme, however, does not work as expected. Because revalidateSub() function stores its own copy of testobj and onUpdateData of each component rewriting the changes of other sub-components...

To be honest, I don't quite understand how to store data correctly for this type of React apps. What do you propose? Maybe I should move the data storage out of React components at all? Or maybe useMemo?

Thank you for the shared experience and examples!

**Update1:** I have coded the example in the Sandbox, please check
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-browser-xf4u0

To see the problem, please click some times to the "Click Me!" button in object 1, you can see the value of obj1 is changing as well as the value of the main object is changing (which is CORRECT). Then click one time to the "Click Me!" of the obj2. You will see (BOOM!) the value of obj1 is reset to its default state. Which is NOT correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this by myself. It turned out, that the setState function may also receive the FUNCTION as a parameter. This function should return a new "state" value.

I have moved `revalidateSub()` function OUT from the EditForm component, so it does not duplicate the state variable "`testobj`" anymore. And it is now working as expected.

[Codebox Page](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-browser-xf4u0)

Comment: I thought about why! I added an update below my answer. read! Thanks, I learned new knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the idea is correct. In React components, when the value of the props passed from the state or the parent component changes, re-rendering should be performed. Recognized as a value.

Because of this issue, when we need to update a multilayered object or array, we have to use ... to create a new object or array with an existing value.
It seems to be wrong during the copying process.

I don't have the full code, so a detailed answer is not possible, but I think the bottom part is the problem.

```js
let t2 = cloneDeep(testobj);
```

There are many other solutions, but trying Immutable.js first will help you find the cause of the problem.

Consider also useReducer.

---

**update**

```js
export default function EditForm(props) {
  const [testobj, setTestobj] = useState({
    sub1: { id: 5, v: 55 },
    sub2: { id: 7, v: 777 },
    sub3: { id: 9, v: 109 }
  });

  function revalidateSub(sub_name, value) {
    let t2 = cloneDeep(testobj);
    t2[sub_name] = value;
    return t2;
  }
  console.log("NEW EditForm instance was created");

  function handleTestClick() {
    let t2 = cloneDeep(testobj);
    t2.sub2.v++;
    setTestobj(t2);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        <Button onClick={handleTestClick} variant="contained" color="secondary">
          Click Me to change from main object
        </Button>
        <p>
          Global value:{" "}
          <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>{JSON.stringify(testobj)}</span>
        </p>
        <MyTestObj
          subobj={testobj["sub1"]}
          ident={"sub1"}
          onUpdateData={(v) => setTestobj((p) => revalidateSub("sub1", v))}
        />
        <MyTestObj
          subobj={testobj["sub2"]}
          ident={"sub2"}
          onUpdateData={(v) => setTestobj((p) => revalidateSub("sub2", v))}
        />
        <MyTestObj
          subobj={testobj["sub3"]}
          ident={"sub3"}
          onUpdateData={(v) => setTestobj((p) => revalidateSub("sub3", v))}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason it bursts when you do the above setState updates the local state asynchronously.

The setState method should be thought of as a single request, not an immediate, synchronous execution. In other words, even if the state is changed through setState, the changed state is not applied immediately after the method is executed.

Thus, your code

```js
setTestobj((p) => revalidateSub(p, "sub3", v))
```

It is safer to use the first parameter of setstate to get the full state like this!

Thanks to this, I was able to gain new knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: I am using the cloneDeep() method of the lodash library, because {...obj} clones only the top-level of sub-objects. I think my idea is not quite correct, because the amount of additional code is too much (I think) and also each copy of the revalidateSub() function makes it's own copy of testobj value.

Comment: What I said was correct was not the beauty of the code, it was only about whether the code worked.  {'obj1': {...obj1}, 'obj2': {...obj2, obj2.a}}, 
What I said... means the following lines of code, but something like lodash's deepcopy behavior. 
I've been using reducer or something else for nested objects because setState didn't work until now, but when I looked up I found out that the reason for my answer was wrong. ==> 
I'll look for a bit more and correct the answer.

Comment: As a result of searching, if the value is copied well from t2, the whole code behavior is correct. 
Maybe it's the other side's problem. And the above comment was not edited, so I write it again. We can use useState for nested objects. Please refer to the following, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react

Comment: Ah... I think I found it... ``` subobj={testobj['sub1']} ```
Here, try passing testobj itself as a sub-component.

Comment: Please check the initial message, I've added a Codebox link so you can see the problem by yourself and play with it.